# Error de sintaxis en ciclo For Java

Tags: java, bucle-for, random

Estoy haciendo una aplicación donde pide cierta cantidad de números aleatorios y una meta.

Para llegar a la meta, se tiene que dividir el numero aleatorio entre la suma de todos los números aleatorios y el resultado que de multiplicarlo por la meta, la formula quedaría mas o menos así:

ValorX = (Numero aleatorio / Suma de números aleatorios) * Meta

Por ejemplo:

- Número aleatorio 1: 0.926618567704436
- Número aleatorio 2: 0.727956240503210
- Número aleatorio 3: 0.005435585904323
- Número aleatorio 4: 0.639513264129861

Suma de números aleatorios: 2.299523658241830

Meta: 40

- Valor 1 = 16
- Valor 2 = 13
- Valor 3 = 0
- Valor 4 = 11

La suma de los cuatro valores es igual a 40.

Mi código de programa es el siguiente:

```
        double random;
        double suma = 0;
        int totalDia;

        for (int i = 1; i <= vDias; i++) {

            random = (Math.random() * 1);

            suma += random;

            totalDia = (int) ((random / suma) * meta);

            TableRow fila = new TableRow(this);
            fila.setId(100 + i);

            TextView tv_col1 = new TextView(this);
            tv_col1.setId(200 + i);
            tv_col1.setText(String.valueOf(i));

            TextView tv_col2 = new TextView(this);
            tv_col2.setId(300 + i);
            tv_col2.setText(String.valueOf(totalDia));

            fila.addView(tv_col1);
            fila.addView(tv_col2);

            tableLayout.addView(fila);
            num_celda = num_celda + 2;

        }
```

La variable vDias es cuantos números aleatorios quiero que genere la aplicación.

Y la aplicación siempre me devuelve como primer resultado el valor de la meta, en este caso 40, y los demás valores al sumarlos no dan 40.

¿Cual podría ser mi error?

Comment: Por favor considera editar y agregar la etiqueta del lenguaje que usas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione de esta manera, poniendo un ciclo For para cada paso, y declarando la variable suma como Private.

```
        double[] random = new double[vDias];
        double[] divRandom = new double[vDias];
        int [] resultado = new int[vDias];

        for (int i = 1; i <= vDias; i++){

            random[i-1] =  Math.random();

            suma += random[i-1];

        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= vDias; i++){

            divRandom[i - 1] = (random[i - 1] / suma)*meta;

        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= vDias; i++){

            resultado [i -1] = (int) Math.round(((divRandom[i -1])*100)/100);

            TableRow fila = new TableRow(this);
            fila.setId(100 + i);

            TextView tv_col1 = new TextView(this);
            tv_col1.setId(200 + i);
            tv_col1.setText(String.valueOf(i));

            TextView tv_col2 = new TextView(this);
            tv_col2.setId(300 + i);
            tv_col2.setText(String.valueOf(resultado[i - 1]));

            fila.addView(tv_col1);
            fila.addView(tv_col2);

            suma = 0;
            tableLayout.addView(fila);
            num_celda = num_celda + 2;
        }
```